# beginner: rolling a dice: frequency and if-else-if?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I show the frequency with which each face of the dice finishes uppermost?

```
//this program stimulates rolling a dice
var outputAreaRef = document.getElementById("outputArea");

var array=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var i=1;
var outString="";
while (i<60000)
{
    var number=Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    array[number]++;
    i++;
}

outputAreaRef.innerHTML = " array: " + array  ;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.  What questions do you have about "6-way if-else-if control structure"?

Comment: The frequency will be 1/6 approx. If you have to log frequencies then each position in the array must start at 0. Make an array 0-5 and increment using your method. You are also forgetting to assign back to the array (array[number] = ++array[number])

Answer (score 3):

I see what you are trying to do and it may be easier to explain here.

You have a couple of issues. Your array should 6 in length, not 7 and all values MUST start with 0 or you will receive a false positive. If Zero is really One then you modify when you output, don't put it in your logic.

The method is correct to increment but the random number should be 0-5.Ultimately you could loop and output or use the console. Console is a far better way to check and debug your code than DOM injection.

If you don't know anything about it please take a look :-)
[Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/command-line/command-line-reference?hl=en)

```
var array=[0,0,0,0,0,0];
var i=1;
while (i<60000)
{
  var number=Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
  ++array[number];
  i++;
}

console.table(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were just missing the output syntax. You'll need to output each index of your array, followed by its value. Try this:

```
//this program stimulates rolling a die
var outputAreaRef = document.getElementById("outputArea");


var array=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var i=1;
var outString="";
while (i<60000)
{
var number=Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
array[number]++;
i++;
}

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    outputAreaRef.innerHTML += i + ": " + array[i] +"<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what I think you're looking for is correct, then this will do it. I changed some of the code to my own preference of how to accomplish this, but the concepts are the same. If you keep using an array, then you can use forEach to iterate through it.

```js
var array = { 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0 };
iterations = 60000;

for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
  var number=Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  array[number]++;
}

document.getElementById("outputArea").innerHTML = " array: " + JSON.stringify(array)  ;

for( var k in array ) {
  array[k] = Math.round((array[k] / iterations) * 1000)/1000;
}

document.getElementById("frequencies").innerHTML = " array: " + JSON.stringify(array)  ;
```

```html
<div id="outputArea"></div>
<div id="frequencies"></div>
```